# MySQL Sort varchar by its integer

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

How do I sort a column (VARCHAR) like this:

```
[CSGO] Bot #1
[CSGO] Bot #2
[CSGO] Bot #3
...
[CSGO] Bot #10
```

My Query results in:

```
[CSGO] Bot #2
[CSGO] Bot #23
[CSGO] Bot #5
[CSGO] Bot #6
```

Query:

```
SELECT bot_id, name, username FROM bots ORDER BY ABS(REPLACE(name, '[CSGO] #', '')) ASC
```

Without the ABS() and REPLACE(), gives basically the same result.

Comment: Looks like your argument in the replace is missing `'Bot'`. It looks the the `REPLACE` function returns an unmodified value of `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this assuming the prefixes are the same length:

```
order by length(name), name
```

If you just want to go by the portion after the #:

```
order by substring_index(name, '#', -1) + 0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Went with `order by substring_index(name, '#', -1) + 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT bot_id, name, username 
FROM bots 
ORDER BY substring_index(name, '#', 1),  substring_index(name, '#', -1) + 0
```

if your column name always starts with '[CSGO] Bot #', then do this:

```
SELECT bot_id, name, username 
FROM bots 
ORDER BY substr(name, 13) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
 ORDER BY ABS(REPLACE(name, '[CSGO] Bot #', ''))*1 ASC
```